# How to protect master API key?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, security, api-key

I created a Restful API, a website (ReactJS/Ruby on Rails), and a mobile app(React Native).

I am using the API to show and process data on the website and the mobile app.

In the website, I am using **jQuery** AJAX requests that somehow looks like this:

```
...some other code
componentDidMount () {
  $.getJSON('https://example.com/api/v1/accounts?key=MASTER-API-KEY', (data) => {
    this.setState({
      accounts: data.accounts
    });
  });
}
...some other code
```

In the mobile app, I am using **fetch** that somehow looks like this:

```
...some other code
fetch('https://example.com/api/v1/accounts?key=MASTER-API-KEY', {
  method: 'GET',
...some other code
```

The users also have their own API keys with limited privilege based on their user level.

I already have the validation to process the request if only they have sent a valid API key. But on the website and the app, I am using a master API key that has access to all.

I believe that this can be seen in the source file on the website and it can be reverse engineered in the mobile app.

The possible solution that I have for the website is to make the process in the server instead of using AJAX, but how can I access it on my ReactJS components?

For the mobile app, should I switch to using Swift/Java and make the request there instead of fetch?

Comment: I wouldn't unlock the treasury because someone sent you a valid API key.  From what I've seen, API keys are pretty much public.  You should do any mission-critical user authorization/authentication through username/password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## WHO and WHAT is accessing the API server

I would like to start by making clear the distinction between **WHAT** and **WHO** is accessing the API server.

The **WHO** is the user of the mobile app that you can authenticate,authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID or OAUTH2 flows.

Now you need a way to identify **WHAT** is calling your API server and here things become more tricky than most developers may think. The **WHAT** is the thing making the request to the API server, is it really your genuine mobile app or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?

Well to identify the **WHAT** developers tend to resort to an API key that usually they hard-code in the code of their mobile app and some go the extra mile and compute it at run-time in the mobile app, thus becomes a dynamic secret in opposition to the former approach that is a static secret embedded in the code.

## The Problem With API Keys

> I already have the validation to process the request if only they have sent a valid API key. But on the website and the app, I am using a master API key that has access to all.
> I believe that this can be seen in the source file on the website and it can be reverse engineered in the mobile app.

In a web app we only need to inspect the source code with the browser dev tools or by right click on view page source and search for the API key.

On the mobile app we can start by doing a quick spy on the binary with the `string` command on linux:

```sh
$ strings -aw app-debug.apk | grep -C 1 '_API_' -
ic_launcher_round
GRADLE_API_KEY
GRADLE_ENV_API_KEY
abc_action_bar_home_description
```

For a more complete and details scan the [MobSF](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) will help you to reverse engineer the mobile app binary in order to extract the API key and enumerate other attack vectors.

> Mobile Security Framework is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing framework capable of performing static analysis, dynamic analysis, malware analysis and web API testing.

So anything that runs on the client side and needs some secret to access an API can be abused in different ways and you can learn more on [this series](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) of articles about Mobile API Security Techniques. This articles will teach you how API Keys, User Access Tokens, HMAC and TLS Pinning can be used to protect the API and how they can be bypassed.

## Defending an API Server

> but how can I access it on my ReactJS components?

Sorry but I don't have the knowledge to help you here, but keep reading to understand what can be done to secure your API server.

> The possible solution that I have for the website is to make the process in the server instead of using AJAX...?
>
> For the mobile app, should I switch to using Swift/Java and make the request there instead of fetch?

A mobile app or a web app should only communicate with a API server that is under your control and any access to third part APIs services must be done by this same API server you control.

This way you limit the attack surface to only one place, where you will employ as many layers of defense as what you are protecting is worth.

For an API serving a web app you can employ several layers of dense, starting with [reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html), followed by [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall)(WAF) and finally if you can afford it a [User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics)(UBA) solution.

Google [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.
>
> ...helps you detect abusive traffic on your website without any user friction. It returns a score based on the interactions with your website and provides you more flexibility to take appropriate actions.

[WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall):

> A web application firewall (or WAF) filters, monitors, and blocks HTTP traffic to and from a web application. A WAF is differentiated from a regular firewall in that a WAF is able to filter the content of specific web applications while regular firewalls serve as a safety gate between servers. By inspecting HTTP traffic, it can prevent attacks stemming from web application security flaws, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), file inclusion, and security misconfigurations.

[UBA - User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics):

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

All this solutions work based on a negative identification model, by other words they try their best to differentiate the bad from the good by identifying what is bad, not what is good, thus they are prone to false positives, despite of the advanced technology used by some of them, like machine learning and artificial intelligence.

So you may find yourself more often than not in having to relax how you block the access to the API server in order to not affect the good users. This also means that this solutions require constant monitoring to validate that the false positives are not blocking your legit users and that at same time they are properly keeping at bay the unauthorized ones.

Regarding APIs serving mobile apps a positive identification model can be used by using a Mobile App Attestation solution that guarantees to the API server that the requests can be trusted without the possibility of false positives.

#### The Mobile App Attestation

The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is to guarantee at run-time that your mobile app was not tampered or is not running in a rooted device by running a SDK in the background that will communicate with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device is running on.

On successful attestation of the mobile app integrity a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud are aware. In the case of failure on the mobile app attestation the JWT token is signed with a secret that the API server does not know.

Now the App must sent with every API call the JWT token in the headers of the request. This will allow the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature and expiration time in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

The Mobile App Attestation service already exists as a SAAS solution at [Approov](https://www.approov.io/approov-in-detail.html)(I work here) that provides SDKs for several platforms, including iOS, Android, React Native and others. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token issued by the cloud service. This check is necessary for the API server to be able to decide what requests to serve and what ones to deny.

## Conclusion

In the end the solution to use in order to protect your API server must be chosen in accordance with the value of what you are trying to protect and the legal requirements for that type of data, like the GDPR regulations in Europe.

So using API keys may sound like locking the door of your home and leave the key under the mat, but not using them is liking leaving your car parked with the door closed, but the key in the ignition.

Answer (score 0):

In React i make a .env file and added my configurations into it.

.env file:

```
REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI="xxxxxx"
REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID="xxxxxxx"
```

If i want to use these params call by following line:

```
const consumer_public_key = process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID;
```

I am not sure about this but you need to write REACT_APP_ to prefix of your params that to call successfully in react.

Answer (score -1):

This should work if you are developing on node (as i guess you are):

[using process.env by hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-keep-your-secret-keys-safe-secure-8b1a7877d69c)